# How to execute more than one swf depending on the XML File

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, output

I have a few Textfields with different contents. That's why I created a XML File and want to read the content into my Textfield. How is it possible to execute this file from Flash Professional CS5 only once, but still have many .swf file outputs?

So here is my XML:

```
<Person>
  <Name>Susanne</Name>
  <Age>12</Age>
  <Gender>f</Gender>
</Person>
<Person>
  <Name>Max</Name>
  <Age>18</Age>
  <Gender>m</Gender>
</Person>
```

If this is not possible, is there a way I can save a variable in this XML File, so that I only have to export the file again and again to have different content?

Comment: First off, read this article to get a handle on how to read the content from you xml: (http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/)
Secondly, it is possible to only display certain content depending on what you want to show given different settings, however, implementation is largely dependant on what you're trying to accomplish and what you have access to.  For instance, if this were a local app, you might pass in a sharedObject which persists between loads.  Conversely, if this were a web-app, you may parse a URL, or PHP call.

Comment: I know how to read the content from my xml, but thanks anyway.

I am not writing an app, this should be a display ad with different content, so if I have the files local, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to create one SWF and then populate the data using flashvars. here's a writeup of how to do that
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/reusable_btn_bc/

the only propblem is that you can't use xml directly, you'll need to use javascript or some other way of parsing the data.

Of course this will only work if you are using an html file

the other way is to use batch compile using the flex or JSFL http://www.scriptocalypse.com/?p=46) compiler